# CircleAvatar se muestra en azul en flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy poniendo un avatar en el drawer, pero se muestra en color azul,
No sé que pasa ya intente poner el listTile en trapasparente pero me lo oculta
se los agradezco de antemano muchas gracias.

```
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
               gradient: LinearGradient(
                   end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                   begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                   colors: <Color>[
                 Color.fromRGBO(137, 168, 170, 1.0),
                 Color.fromRGBO(69, 84, 85, 1.0)
               ])),
           child: new ListTile(
             leading: CircleAvatar(
             //  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
               backgroundImage: NetworkImage('../../assets/icons/user.png'),
             ),
             title: Text('Hola',
                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
           ),
         ),
         new ListTile(
           title: Text("menu1"),
           onTap: () {},
         )
```

Comment: Podrías agrega una imagen de como se aprecia? está tomando el color del background del scaffold

Comment: Ya, agregue la imagen de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: si le pones backgroundColor: Colors.red, que aparece?

Comment: Se pone en color rojo, lo puse en color trasparente pero me la oculta

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me quedo la razón era porque no estaba bien configurado el pubspec.yaml y utilice la propiedad AssetImage

Comment: dale, te invito a mi canal para q veas algo de flutter avanzado youtube.com/diegoveloper

Answer (score 0):

La razón era porque no estaba bien configurado el pubspec.yaml y la propiedad utiliza la propiedad AssetImage

Comment: Si agregas más detalle o el código que utilizaste podrías ayudar a mas personas con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

estas haciendo referencia a un assets en tu app y no al networkimage:

Deberia quedar:

```
backgroundImage: NetworkImage('www.dominio.com/user.png')
```

o Asi

```
backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/icons/user.png')
```

Dependiendo de donde quieras obtener tu imagen.

- Recuerdas si vas a usar imagenes locales (que estan en tu proyecto), debes especificarlo en tu pubspec.yaml

  ```
  assets:
    - directory/
    - directory/subdirectory/
  ```